# Why does this Left Join in Coldfusion/MySQL cause an endless loop?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, left-join, infinite-loop

I'm running a search query in Coldfusion8 (MySQL 5.0.88).

The query constructs a LEFT JOIN in Coldfusion like so:

```
<cfquery datasource="db" name="q">
    SELECT ...
</cfscript>
```

and loops over the results to create the MySQL query syntax:

```
<cfset variables.pl= "LEFT JOIN pricelists p ON ">
<cfloop query="q" >
    <cfscript>
    if( q.listitem IS '' )    
        variables.pl = variables.pl & '(a.iln = p.iln AND p.pl= "-Standard-" AND p.ean = a.ean AND p.iln = "#q.iln_verkaeufer#") OR ';
    else
        variables.pl= variables.pl & '(a.iln = p.iln AND p.pl= "#q.pl#" AND p.ean = a.ean AND p.iln = "#q.userID#") OR
    </cfscript>
</cfloop>
<cfset variables.pl= variables.pl& "(1=0)">
```

So the final will look something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN plist p ON (p.iln = a.iln AND p.pl= "-Standard-" AND p.iln = "1111111111111") OR (p.iln = a.iln AND p.pl= "I" AND p.iln = "1111122222221") OR (1=0)
```

Which is fed into the actual query synatx:

```
SELECT art, count(*) as number
    FROM article a
    <cfqueryparam value="#variables.pl#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar">
WHERE ...
```

If I try to trigger this, the server just hangs up and I need to restart the browser tab to end the session. I have removed all other search criteria from my select. The error is caused be the cfqueryparam feeding my text contstruct.

However I don't know what the problem could be, because I never get an error. The browser just goes dead, so I guess I'm creating some kind of endless loop.

**Question**
Can anyone tell from my code what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I managed to go from Server hangup to a commit error. But since the script is triggered by an Ajax call and I cannot remotely access CFadmin, I need to blindguess what the problem could be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing here isn't the purpose of cfqueryparam and I'd suggest reading up on the proper usage of cfqueryparam - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html

Refactoring your code to something like below should work as you have intended. I replaced the script for tags, just at my preference, feel free to use script if that's your preference.

```
<cfquery ...>
SELECT art, count(*) as number
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN pricelists p ON
<cfloop query="q" >
<cfif q.listitem IS ''>
    (a.iln = p.iln
    AND p.pl= "-Standard-"
    AND p.ean = a.ean
    AND p.iln = <cfqueryparam value='#q.iln_verkaeufer#' />
    )
<cfelse>
    (a.iln = p.iln
    AND p.pl= <cfqueryparam value="#q.pl#"/>
    AND p.ean = a.ean
    AND p.iln = <cfqueryparam value="#q.userID#" />
    )
</cfif>
<cfif NOT q.isLast()>OR</cfif>
</cfloop>
WHERE ...
</cfquery>
```

Comment: oh. this is much nicer. I inherited the original script and am trying to make something out of it

Comment: hm. using your example, which I like a lot. But I cannot get a flag from after the query or any query results. Even a cfdump after the query doesn't trigger. Need to look into this some more